# Payfort Intergration Issue (Technical Problem 00006)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, payfort

I am getting the following error on payfort checkout page

> Failed!
> Error code: 00006
> Error Message: Technical problem

My access_code, merchant_identifier and SHA_Request_Phrase are fine (not present in code).

The code I wrote:

```
<?php
$shaString  = '';
$amount = 1000;

// array request
$arrData    = array(
    'command'            => 'AUTHORIZATION',
    'access_code'        => $access_code,
    'merchant_identifier' => $merchant_identifier,
    'merchant_reference'  => 'Test010',
    'amount'             => $amount,
    'currency'           => 'AED',
    'language'           => 'en',
    'customer_email'     => 'shahmeerzahoor007@gmail.com',
    'order_description'  => 'iPhone 6-S',
);
// sort an array by key
ksort($arrData);
foreach ($arrData as $key => $value) {
    $shaString .= "$key=$value";
}

$shaString = $requestPhrase . $shaString . $requestPhrase;
$signature = hash("sha256", $shaString);

echo "Signature >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> $signature";


$requestParams['signature'] = $signature;

$redirectUrl = 'https://sbcheckout.payfort.com/FortAPI/paymentPage';

// Output the HTML form
echo "<html xmlns='https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>\n<head></head>\n<body>\n";
echo "<form action='$redirectUrl' method='post' name='frm'>\n";
foreach ($requestParams as $a => $b) {
    echo "\t<input type='hidden' name='" . htmlentities($a) . "' value='" . htmlentities($b) . "'>\n";
}
echo "\t<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
echo "\t\tdocument.frm.submit();\n";
echo "\t</script>\n";
echo "</form>\n</body>\n</html>";
?>
```

I have tried reaching out to their support but havent worked at all.